# Python on Windows - subprocess.check_output with full-path works not?

Tags: python, python-3.x

With `args=['e:\\lynx\\lynx.exe','-dump',some_url]`, 
`subprocess.check_output` works fine if the current-directory is e:\lynx.

Elsewhere, it fails with a CalledProcessException and retcode of -1.

For now, I do not wish to add e:\lynx to PATH.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem in making the current directory `e:\\lynx` from withing python? That seems like a good solution to me.